# How to Increase Speed of Cube on finger touch in Android OpenGL?

Tags: android

I am working on an Android application in which I am facing a problem regarding rotation  of 3D Cube.I want to rotate my cube according to fingure touch.

- If User Touch Fast speed on mobile screen then cube should be move fast and stop slowly -2 after some time .
- And if user Touch slowly then cube should be move slowly.

Till Now I have tried this code which is not working for rotation--

```
            //Rotate around the axis based on the rotation matrix (rotation, x, y, z)
    gl.glRotatef(PhotoCube3DLWPActivity.xrot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);    //X
    gl.glRotatef(PhotoCube3DLWPActivity.yrot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);    //Y
    gl.glRotatef(PhotoCube3DLWPActivity.zrot, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);    //Z

    cube.draw(gl);                  //Draw the Cube 

    //Change rotation factors (nice rotation)
    PhotoCube3DLWPActivity.xrot +=0.3f;;
    PhotoCube3DLWPActivity.yrot +=0.2f;
    PhotoCube3DLWPActivity.zrot +=0.4f;
```

where xrot,yrot and zrot are static variable of PhotoCube3DLWPActivity class which values are 0.3f,0.2f and 0.4f respectiblly.

for Touch event I am using-

```
     @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                Log.i("check", "Hey action down");
                downX = event.getX();
                downY = event.getY();
                downTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
                // handle in between rotation

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                Log.i("check", "Hey action up");
                diffX = event.getX() - downX;
                diffY = event.getY() - downY;
                diffTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - downTime;

                diffTouch = (float) Math.sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY);

                diffSpeed = diffTouch / diffTime * 1.0f;

                diffAngle = (float) Math.atan(diffY / diffX);

                xrot += diffSpeed * Math.sin(diffAngle);
                yrot += diffSpeed * Math.cos(diffAngle);

                break;
        }

    }//touch end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try implementing a simple Fling gesture detection, and based on the velocity, you could adjust the speed of the rotation.

To implement the GestureDetector, you could look into the following,

[Fling Gesture](http://www.monkeycancode.com/simple-gesture-fling)